# Failed to resolve module specifier "react"

Tags: reactjs

i serve a react app with express and when i run the server in browser console,this error show up;

```
`Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “react” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>iron.com</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-3893ee5f.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-32e10dd3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Node modules should be added to your `package.json` via `npm install name_of_your_package`. You should NOT add them manually in `index.html`.

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "@green-api/whatsapp-api-client": "^0.3.37",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "config": "^3.3.9",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expr-eval": "^2.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "joi": "^17.9.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.11.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2"
  }
}

Comment: this is my package.json and react included @EmilKarlsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should above the title import :

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "react": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js",
        "react-router-dom": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/6.17.0/react-router-dom.production.min.js",
        "react-toastify":"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-toastify@9.1.3/dist/react-toastify.min.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
```

this should solve your problem for everyone came up to this

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me better with https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/+esm but i just learned something new :)